# How to redirect with Nginx my Kibana and Jupyter Cluster

Tags: nginx

[image]Hello I have a problem with the nginx.conf.

On / I put an index.html with two buttons which will redirect me to either Jupyter or Kibana Cluster UI.

And then I redirect my jupyter and kibana cluster on two differents urls.

But I'm actually totally new to nginx and in the Jupyter case, my page doesn't load at all. It gives me 404 code when he wants to get the static css/js open source files of Jupyter.

If I put the jupyter redireciton directly on the location / then this works perfectly. And same for Kibana, but I need both of them in one nginx.conf

```
server {
        listen                  80;
        server_name             mydomain.name.com;   ## Replace with your domain name
        return                  301 https://$server_name;
}

server {
        listen                  443 ;
        ssl                     on;
        server_name             mydomain.name.com; ## Replace with your domain name
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;  ## Replace with your own certificate
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
        access_log              /var/log/nginx/kibana.access.log;
        error_log               /var/log/nginx/kibana.error.log;

 location / {
         root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
         index  index.html;
         include        fastcgi_params;
         include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    }
        location /jupyter {
            proxy_pass https://10.33.1.164:8888;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
     location ~ ^/jupyter/(api/kernels/[^/]+/(channels|iopub|shell|stdin)|terminals/websocket)/? {
            proxy_pass https://10.33.1.164:8888;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            # WebSocket support
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
#            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

        }

  location /kibana {
                proxy_pass              http://10.33.1.145:5601/;
                proxy_http_version  1.1;
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you need to configure Jupyter and Kibana to expect them to be running at a `base_url`

For Jupter you need to set `NotebookApp.base_url` to `/jupyter`. See below for details

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html

For Kibana you need to set `basePath` in config `/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml`

```
server.basePath: "/kibana"
```

Then it should work. Also make sure to change proxy pass for Kibana to

```
proxy_pass              http://10.33.1.145:5601;
```

The trailing `/` changes the url handling

Comment: server.basePath: "/kibana" When i do this, my kibana doesn't even start anynmore. My kibana is on another than my nginx should I change the host and port fields too ? Because I tried and it doesn't give anything

Comment: First try to get kibana working on its own IP:port/kibana. Which version of Kibana are you using?

Comment: What's wierd is that there is only one ip which works : server.ip : 0.0.0.0 and I use Kibana 5.1

Comment: 5.1 should allow the basePath. You need to see why it doesn't start. Also check `http://10.33.1.145:5601/kibana` after setting it up